# Bootstrap 3.0 affix doesn't work when body has overflow-x:hidden

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, affix

I don't know why but when you have the CSS style `overflow-x:hidden` on the body element then the affix plugin does not work. It simply refuses to switch between affix, affix-top and affix bottom.

I'm guessing it fails to detect or measure the scroll position but I have no idea why `overflow-x:hidden` could be causing this.

Unfortunately I need `overflow-x:hidden` so removing it is not a good work-around.

Any ideas on how/where to look?

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the age of your post, you resolved your issue a different way. But I just came across the same problem and found a solution so will post it here for anybody else who is experiencing the same problem:

The affix function indeed breaks when `html, body {overflow-x:hidden;}` is set.

But if you use `html .container, body .container {overflow-x:hidden;}` in your CSS instead, it works perfectly and there is no horizontal scrolling on the mobile.

You will have to put this CSS into a media query to apply it only to mobile though.